# Displaying word letter by letter

Tags: java

How would I do this?

> Give me a word > sugar
>
> s
>
> su
>
> sug
>
> suga
>
> sugar

Here is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a word:");
    String word = scan.nextLine();
    int length = word.length();
    for(int number = 0; number < length; number++){
        System.out.println(word.charAt(number));
    }
}
```

This makes the word display letter by letter.

Comment: *"I did this, and it makes the word display letter by letter"*...and isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: No, it outputs this:
S
u
g
a
r instead of s su sug suga sugar

Comment: Louie, you really should mark an accepted answer on your questions by clicking the green checkmark under the vote count if the answer helped you and is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to use a form of `String` concaternation...

```
String word = "Sugar";
int length = word.length();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(word.length());
for (int number = 0; number < length; number++) {
    sb.append(word.charAt(number));
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Basically, this appends each character to the builder on each loop, printing the results...

```
S
Su
Sug
Suga
Sugar
```

Another approach might be to use a compound loop...

```
String word = "Sugar";
int length = word.length();
for (int number = 0; number < length; number++) {
    for (int inner = 0; inner < number; inner++) {
        System.out.print(word.charAt(inner));
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

The outer (first) loop controls the number of characters you want to print, the inner (second) loop physically prints each character from the start to the number of characters you want to print...(nb: This will print a leading empty space, so you might need a `if` in there to control that if it's important)

Comment: @AlexK Because the OP may not be allowed to use `subString`, because it doesn't create temporary objects within the loop, making it more efficient, because there are more than one way to skin this cat...

Comment: Gotcha. I was just wondering...didn't mean that there was only one way to do it!

Comment: The second option is the clearest solution if `substring()` is not allowed. +1

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using `String.substring(int startIndex, int endIndex)`.

For you, your program would look like this:

```
String s = "Sugar";
for(int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
    System.out.println(s.substring(0,i)); 
}
```

Keep in mind that startIndex is inclusive, endIndex is exclusive. So `"Sugar".substring(0,3)` will give "Sug".

Comment: @MadProgrammer `substring()` is more efficient than the StringBuilder since it is reusing the original `char[]` from the source string. `sb.toString()` creates a new String object anyways...

Comment: But `subString` it's still creating a new `String` from the `char` array on each loop...

Comment: (and I wanted to demonstrate a means of `String` concatenation over using `String + String`, which is really bad)

Comment: @MadProgrammer a String holds a `char[]`, the start index and the end index. `String.substring()` creates a new String object, but reuses the `char[]`, with different start/end indexes. It is still much better than `String+String` and `sb.toString()` since both create a `new char[]` besides the `new String()`.

Comment: @GaborSch It depends on the use case.

Comment: @GaborSch Actually `String(char[], int, int)` creates a new copy of the `char` - `this.value = Arrays.copyOfRange(value, offset, offset+count);`, so, not alot of difference.  When it comes to `String` concatenation (especially within a loop), `StringBuilder` would be a slightly better method, that's all :) - In this case, that would mean that `StringBuilder` is creating a single `char` array, once, and a new `String` on each loop, instead of a new `char` array and a new `String` on each loop...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Correct. In the current example - since we do create a String for each iteration in the loop - it is technically the same. Generally speaking, `StringBuilder` is clearly better than `String+String`.